# NSString and NSMutableString memory considerations

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsstring

I am trying to wrap my head around NSString and NSMutableString, and how they affect memory.

In my research, I've concluded that if I create an NSString object and give it a value, then change the value later, the original object is replaced by another with the new value.

My question is, in the case of changing the value of an NSString. When the value of the NSString is changed and the object pointed to is replaced by a new object, what happens to the original object? Is this a memory leak?

Thanks! V

Comment: Interestingly, no one has addresses Mutability (NSMutableString), a key part of the question.

Comment: @Zaph There was no question about `NSMutableString` :)

Comment: The title and first sentence have the word "NSMutableString" in them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original `NSString` will be released by the system and so, won't cause any leak.

Comment: As with any object, not just `NSString`s. Side rambling: that's why ARC is not so good for newcomers. To use the magic at its full potential, one has to understand the deep roots behind it.

Comment: This is true under some circumstances and not true under others.

Comment: @Cyrille sure, but if you try to teach retain counting management and memory management to a newcomer on first lesson, you won't see him on the second I think ^^

Comment: @Cyrille I think you are falling into a trap of assuming that your level of knowledge is the base everyone needs. This is not true. Most, perhaps including you, do not know how the OS actually allocates memory, above that is how malloc/calloc/realloc work, below that how the CPU caches and virtual memory are implemented. Even MRR holds many mysteries knowledge about which is generally not necessary. I see this often among newbies (to me that is someone with less than 20+ years of software development experience, long enough to see the "must know" turn into the "not necessary to know").

Comment: @Cyrille Quick question: Given the memory address of an object, can you tell me it's actual hardware address? That used to be something we all knew and needed to know. Times change, levels of necessary knowledge change.

Comment: @Zaph *"must know" turn into the "not necessary to know"* I like it :D

Comment: @Zaph: Given the large number of questions here that are based on a confusion of how retain-counting works, I think you're overly optimistic about where the "base every needs" is. It is clear that many people still write MRR programs — and we don't even know that the OP isn't one of them.

Comment: Sure some level of understanding is needed and it is different for MRR and ARC. I am not totally basing my comment on @Cyrille, I have co-workers who believe in the same way, whatever their level it they believe that is the minimum needed. To me that seems like a fallacy. Antonio is an example of a poor understanding yet in a manner that is not really harmful. Yet he supposes that his level of understanding is sufficient and a base requirement (he posted an answer after all.

Comment: @Chuck People shouldn't write MRR code and that's double true for newcomers. ARC requires us to think not in retain counts, but in strong references. My answer would be: **Since you disposed your strong reference to the first NSString, you should consider it being already deallocated.**

Comment: @iMartin: I don't disagree with you, but that doesn't make it sensible to just ignore the possibility that they might be using MRR. I also don't think people should dereference uninitialized pointers, but I wouldn't answer the question "Is it always safe to dereference a pointer?" with "Yes." The fact that it's *conditionally safe* as long as people take all the precautions you would doesn't justify an unconditional "Yes, that is safe" — a good answer would explain the conditions under which it is or isn't safe.

Comment: I agreee with all of you (and didn't though of starting such a discussion). I never said it was an absolute necessity, but I am spending some time every day reviewing the code from my freshest developers, and I feel like a little refresher on the real functioning of ARC would be of some use to them. I'm not saying they have to learn how to develop with MRR, or in assembly FWIW. Just that it's good to have a minimal but clear understanding of what's going on behind the scenes in terms of allocations/releases.

Answer (score 2):

`NSString`s can contain string literals, which are compile time constants, and string objects, which instead are instantiated dynamically at runtime.

In case of **string literals**, there is no dynamic instantiation, so they won't affect memory at runtime. Assigning a literal value to a `NSString` variable

```
NSString *myString = @"string1";
```

then assigning another literal value

```
myString = @"string2";
```

doesn't make any change to the amount of available memory.

In case of **string objects** instead memory does change. If you have a variable of type `NSString` and assign it a dynamic string, such as

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"String %d", 1];
```

a new `NSString` instance is allocated, initialized with the provided string, and assigned to the `myString` variable.

If later you assign a new dynamic value

```
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"String %d", 2];
```

a new `NSString` instance is created, but it doesn't replace the old one. Both are instantiated and in memory.

When using ARC though the first `NSString` instance, if no longer referenced,  will be released because not being used. This is handled automatically, so nothing must be done from code.

Maybe you're more interested in the fact that at some time the new and old instances use memory - but that's temporary until the unused instance is released.

To answer to your concern, no, there is no memory leak. String literals persist for the entire app lifetime, since they are constants. String objects are allocated and released (deallocated), and deallocation is automatically handled by ARC.

Of course this is a general concept that applies to any dynamically instantiated class, not just `NSString` - but doesn't apply to primitive data type (int, boolean, float, etc.), because variables of those types hold the actual value, not a pointer to the area in memory where the value is. In case you are wondering, primitive data types don't generate memory leaks.

Comment: String literals don't actually cause allocation. Unlike array, dictionary and NSNumber literals, NSString literals are actually compile-time constants.

Comment: I'm confused with the update & fix. Why on earth would you want to avoid a string literal? I would actively seek to use it. Secondly, how would we use a string literal? In Java I would write ``String s = "foobar";`` to use a string literal (good idea), and I would write ``String s = new String("foobar");`` to create a new instance (bad idea).

Comment: @Gonzalo: You'd want to avoid string literals if you were trying to demonstrate object allocation, since string literals don't allocate anything.

Comment: Agreed. In the context of the question, though, which deals with memory considerations, I'd expect that we would like to use string literals wherever possible.

Comment: @Gonzalo raises a problem, and I agree that the way I answered can generate confusion. I'll amend my answer to explain both cases more clearly

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer making a clear distinction between literals and dynamic strings. Thanks again for pointing that out